# After converting Liquibase XML changelogs to YAML format the error "relation already exists" comes up

Tags: java, spring-boot, liquibase

After converting my XML liquibase changelog and master files to YAML format, I get the error "relation tableName already exists".

If I switch back to XML format, everything works fine. I couldn't find any difference in the changelog files between YAML and XML, but it doesn't work.

Do I need to switch back to XML or what is the problem there?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: check if checksums match between xml and yaml. I think they are different and you will need to create `validCheckSum` for each new yaml entry.

Comment: +1 to bilak's answer.  liquibase is checking the databasechangelog for entries that match the changeset id, author and checksum.  It may think the YAML are different new changesets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from @bilak in original post:

check if checksums match between xml and yaml. I think they are different and you will need to create validCheckSum for each new yaml entry.